# Extra orphaned character in email from nodemailer template email

Tags: javascript, html, nodemailer

I'm using `"nodemailer": "^6.5.0"` to send emails using a HTML template. Everything is working fine except for when I map an array field, I get an extra `,` character after each item and I can't work out where it's comming from.

[image: extra characters]

This is the HTML element from the rendered email copied straight from the Chrome inspector in Gmail:

```
<div>
  <p><b>Brad Stewart 11-03-21 15:26:</b> Another note...</p>
  ,
  <p><b>Brad Stewart 11-03-21 15:44:</b> And another note ...</p>
  ,
  <p><b>Brad Stewart 14-03-21 13:07:</b> test again</p>
  ,
  <p><b>Brad Stewart 14-03-21 13:15:</b> And testing again...</p>
</div>
```

This is the section of the HTML template

```
`<p>
  <b>Notes:</b>
  <div>
    ${task.notes
        ? task.notes.map(
            (note) =>
              `<p><b>- ${note.created_by_name} ${moment(note.date)
                .tz('Australia/Perth')
                .format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm')}:</b> ${note.note}</p>`
          )
        : '-'
    }
  </div>
</p>`
```

Thanks for any help or ideas to remove these orphaned characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is converted to a string by calling [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) since it's inside [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The `toString` method returns the array elements joined by commas as a string.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#description),

> JavaScript calls the `toString` method automatically when an array is to be represented as a text value or when an array is referred to in a string concatenation.

```js
const arr = ['Note 1', 'Note 2', 'Note 3']
console.log(`Notes: ${arr}`)
console.log(arr.toString())
```

You can use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to explicitly convert it to a string.

```
task.notes
  .map(
    (note) =>
      `<p><b>- ${note.created_by_name} ${moment(note.date)
        .tz('Australia/Perth')
        .format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm')}:</b> ${note.note}</p>`
  )
  .join('')
```

Comment: Thanks, Arun Kumar Mohan -  that worked perfectly!

Comment: @BradStewart No worries!